# How do I search if a value is inside the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files called master_registry.csv and master_reference.csv. By using those CSV I have created some new data frames called 'df' and 'df2'. By combining those 'df' and 'df2' data frames I have created a new data frame called 'new_df'. The problem is I want to find a value is inside this 'new_df' data frame. But when I'm trying to get the result It gives me an error.

**This is the code**

```
    # reading csv from the directory
    df = pd.read_csv('application/master_registry.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('application/master_reference.csv')

    # filtering some selected columns form the csv
    df = df.filter(items=['Master_ID', 'Provider First Name', 'Provider Middle Name', 'Provider Last Name (Legal Name)', 'Provider Credential Text', 'Provider Gender Code','Provider License Number State Code_1',
                    'Provider Business Practice Location Address City Name'])

    # creating new data frame with "full name" column
    df['Full_Name'] = df[['Provider First Name', 'Provider Last Name (Legal Name)']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)

    new_df = df.set_index('Master_ID').join(df2.set_index('Master_ID'))

    # selecting rows according to the external values
    main = new_df[(new_df['Master_ID']==master_id)]
    print(main.values.tolist())
```

**When I try the above code It gives me this error.**

> C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1164:
>   FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>         result = method(y)
>       [2018-06-15 14:36:07,148] ERROR in app: Exception on /search/manual/results/by_npi [POST]
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 2292, in wsgi_app
>           response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
>           rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1718, in handle_user_exception
>           reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 35, in reraise
>           raise value
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
>           rv = self.dispatch_request()
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1799, in dispatch_request
>           return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Desktop\Jericho_v0.0.7\application\routes.py",
>   line 41, in search_manual_results_by_npi
>           info = hub.process_search_by_npi(npi)
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Desktop\Jericho_v0.0.7\application\hub.py",
>   line 152, in process_search_by_npi
>           print(new_df['Client_Reference_ID']==npi)
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 1253, in wrapper
>           res = na_op(values, other)
>         File "C:\Users\ChampsoftWK26\Envs\jerich_core\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 1166, in na_op
>           raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
>       TypeError: invalid type comparison
>       127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2018 14:36:07] "POST /search/manual/results/by_npi HTTP/1.1" 500 -

**The new_df is like this**

```
             Provider First Name         ...         Client_Reference_ID
Master_ID                             ...                            
1                     WILLIAM         ...                  1588667638
2                     RICHARD         ...                  1114920261
3                   FRANCISCO         ...                  1861495814
4                        ERIC         ...                  1306849336
5                     RICHARD         ...                  1326041476
6                      GHAITH         ...                  1770586828
7                      TREVOR         ...                  1124021274
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of new_df and the expected output?

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: I think this is the line that give me the error

Comment: `main = new_df[(new_df['Master_ID']==master_id)]`

Comment: so how can I compare some value with index

Comment: What data type is `master_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the row by index, try the following:

```
 main = new_df.loc[[master_id]]
```

For example

```
new_df.loc[[2]]
```

Returns

```
             Provider First Name     Client_Reference_ID
Master_ID                                                      
2                 RICHARD                 1114920261
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Master_ID` is your index. In this case this should work:

```
'your id' in new_df.index
```

Which gives `true` or `false` if the index exist.

Or transform it into a column and then continue with your code:

```
new_df['Master_ID'] = df.index
main = new_df[(new_df['Master_ID']==master_id)]
```

Comment: I agree, but he didnt explain what the output is, so im just guessing. In the same way im guessing that it is the index

Comment: Are you sure that master_id is a column and not the index?

Comment: yes, and then: new_df = df.set_index('Master_ID').join(df2.set_index('Master_ID')). Anyway not point in discuss in the comments. If you have a better solutions please post it :) I think @Isma's solutions is quite good anyway

Comment: @roganjosh no will to provoke, just learn and improve skills and answers :)

Comment: "Thrown me" is a colloquialism where I am from meaning "You've made a good point that's confused the point I was trying to make". Nothing provocative :)  I'll clear my comments up shortly.